# Are react stateless components equal to ReacDOM.PureComponents

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, web-component

As per documentation(https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#react.purecomponent)

> "React.PureComponent is exactly like React.Component but implements
>   shouldComponentUpdate() with a shallow prop and state comparison."

So if I define something like following,

```
const MyView = () => {
  return (
    <div>Hello Stateless Component</div>
  )
};
```

is it a React.PureComponent? Does it do a shallow prop and state comparison?

Comment: I don't think it is. A component that extends `React.PureComponent` is considered a pure component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### They are not equal at all.

Stateless component or the official name `React Stateless Functional Component(RSFC)` has no "state".

React components receive props for passing arguments from outside and use `state` object as `inside state control object`, we call `setState` function to modify `state` object to trigger rerender of the component, `RSFC` only receive props and return corresponding JSX elements, it has no "inside state" object.

`PureComponent` is `React.PureComopnent`, it's not a generic term for a class of components, it's the `React.PureComponent` class which can be extended from, and we use

```
class MyComponent extends React.PureComponent{}
```

tell react that `MyComponent` **is** a pure component.

if you want a `<Clock/>` component show and update time itself, you should use `PureComponent` and there no way to control time update in `RSFC`

more info about `differences between Component and PureComponent` [this article](https://hackernoon.com/react-stateless-functional-components-nine-wins-you-might-have-overlooked-997b0d933dbc) may be the help.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you have written component is functional component and it is not Pure Component.

Pure Component means you know that if component get same props and state again it doesn't need to re-render itself or its child component so it returns false from shouldComponentUpdate method so that componentWillUpdate, render and componentDidUpdate doesn't executed.